# Gintoki's example: Shy school girl becomes slutty after mysterious summer holiday

Tags: gintama

I want to know the season and the episode number in which the following scene occurs.

Gintoki speaks with some people (maybe with Kaguya-chan and megane-kun). I don't remember the topic of speech but he gives this as a supporting example: There is a very shy and cute school girl. After the summer holiday, she becomes very arrogant and slutty with a lot of make up on her face. Gintoki says that something must have happened in the summer. While Gintoki gives this example, we watch before & after images of the girl on the screen.

Comment: possibly episode 203, its called "Everyone Looks Pretty Grown up after Summer Break" http://gintama.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_203

Comment: No. You can't find it by looking the episode title. It is a 10-second joke not directly related to the main arc, that only hardcore Gintama fans can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is from [**Episode 136**](http://gintama.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_136) (season 1), an episode of Hasegawa looking for a 1LDK room.

The scene is about Gintoki giving a nonsense analogy to Hasegawa explaining that a good room has already been "done" by the time you meet, just like girl xD.

[image: analogy example]
[image: before summer]
[image: after summer]
[image: conclusion]

To be exact, the scene starts at minute 17:20. Happy rewatching ^^